# PHP Application odd slow TTFB

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I'm unsure why but my PHP application seems to have a lot of green (TTFB) in the Chrome developer network tab at random visits to the same page the results can often jump around a lot. This can sometimes go as high as 1.5/2 seconds of pure TTFB after some time of activity for a single page load.

For example:
If I were browsing a page on my application actively it would deliver the pages in a very fast TTFB but if I came back 10 minutes later then refreshed the page it would have this long TTFB delay.

I originally thought this was due to headers being sent at the very beginning of my index.php however after moving them further on nearer to the end this issue is still present.

Is it possible to log and monitor/diagnose this? Is this typically seen in most web applications? I noticed a number of other sites responded faster the 2nd request however they aren't as noticeable.

Comment: This sounds a lot like caches being rebuilt. Without deeper knowledge of your application, there is no way to provide you with a statisfying answer, though.

Comment: I think that might be quite possible but I'm not positive and not sure how I would change this, I can provide information you may need, just fire away to as what more information should you require about my application :)